# jQuery detach, prepend and condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div elements that are clickable. When  I click one that contains "1" it will give it class="active", when I click one that contains "2" it will give it class="active" and remove class="active" from the 1st one. Basically it is like switch.

```
<div class="active">1</div>
<div class="">2</div>
```

then this block:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item " data-id="1" data="carousel-item"></div>
  <div class="carousel-item " data-id="2" data="carousel-item"></div>
</div>
```

and after all this code: which is supposed to detach div that don't have data-id of "active" div. When switched, it's supposed to re-attach detached div and detach the second one.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $("div:contains('1')"), 
        b; 
      if (a.hasClass('active')){ 
        b = $("[data-id!='1'][data='carousel-item']").detach(); 
      } 
      else{ 
         $(".carousel-inner").prepend(b);
      } 
}); 
</script>
```

however, it is not working. when I switch (class active moves from one div to another) nothing happens. only first div is detached but on switch it is not reattaching. Any ideas why ? Thanks for any help !

PS: 1. For certain reasons (FU mobirise) I'm not able to manipulate with those two divs with active class(give them onclick() attribute, new class or id and so on).
    2. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Where exactly are you doing the swap logic?  I don't see a click handler in your question.

Comment: I didn't include that. It's external and as i said I am not able to manipulate with that swap logic for certain reasons. So, it makes no sense to include that. If i could manipulate with that swap logic i wouldn't try to solve that this stupid way

Comment: But it does.  That event is what would trigger the swapping of the carousel-items.  As you have it, nothing in your document ready is in anything that would ever repeat evaluation.

Comment: oh yea... you're right... so it won't work with conditions ? how could i make it to repeat evaluation ?

Comment: Javascript does not implicitly repeat code.  That is why constructs such as event handlers and loops exist.  To tell javascript when it *should* repeat

Comment: You should be able to attach your own click handlers to those top divs, and handle the click.  The other logic woudl swap the active class and then your logic would look for which one is active and evaluate the carousel item changes.  Elements are not restricted to having only one event handler per event type

Comment: @Taplar I'm really not able to do that because of Mobirise (or at least i dont know how to) However i can add click handler on div above that divs. Can that help me somehow ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution.  I changed around how you were doing the swap so it isn't doing a detach.  But it should give you an idea of how to potentially do it, if you did want to do the detach anyway.

```js
//emulate the external logic that swaps the active class
$(function(){
  var $elements = $('.top');
  
  $elements.on('click', function(){
    $elements.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});

$(function(){
  var $top = $('.top');
  var $carousel = $('.carousel-inner');
  var $carouselItems = $carousel.find('.carousel-item');
  
  $top.on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $carousel.prepend($carouselItems.filter(function(){
      return $this.data('id') === $(this).data('id');
    }));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top active" data-id="1">1</div>
<div class="top" data-id="2">2</div>

<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item " data-id="1" data="carousel-item">Number 1</div>
  <div class="carousel-item " data-id="2" data="carousel-item">Number 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, Yes i would do that same way, But I tell you I am not able to add that "top" class to those divs... that is the only reason why i have this problem

Comment: You don't have to do that top class.  However you come about with a selector to select those divs, all you need is a reference to them.  I just used the class in my solution for ease. @JúliusĽuptovec

Comment: Oh ye... i can use :contains to refer to them... okay thank you